# Why can't I publish this specific package to a private NPM registry hosted by Verdaccio?

Tags: npm, npm-publish, verdaccio

I'm using Verdaccio to host a private NPM registry on a machine that doesn't have access to the internet. So far, I've successfully published thousands of packages to the registry. However, when trying to publish `hoist-non-react-statics-3.3.2-latest.tgz`, I get the following error: "This command requires you to be logged in. You need to authorize this machine using 'npm adduser'." The thing is, I *have* added myself as a user (which is why I've been able to publish so many packages already), and I've confirmed that I'm logged in via `npm whoami`. I've also done an `npm logout` and an `npm login`. I've also tried turning off user authentication in Verdaccio (https://verdaccio.org/docs/authentication/). Unfortunately, nothing I've tried is letting me publish this package to the registry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into `node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/publish.js`, I realized the registry it's trying to use when checking that I'm authenticated was the public NPM registry, not my self-hosted registry. The solution was to remove these lines of code from `hoist-non-react-statics`'s `package.json` file before publishing it: https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics/blob/master/package.json#L49-L51.

Comment: Pull requests for this package and another package that was causing me the same problem: (1) https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics/pull/116, (2) https://github.com/apideck-libraries/better-ajv-errors/pull/17.